# Test Cafe - Getting error on clicking link which is invisible using Client Function

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have to click on a button that is invisible in `Html`. I tried using Client Function but I am getting an error for the element

```
import { Selector,ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
fixture('Clicking Invisible link').page('http://example.com');

test('Click on invisible link', async t => {
  const viewProgram = Selector('tbody [viewBox]').nth(0);
  const clickViewProgram = ClientFunction(() => viewProgram().click());
  await clickViewProgram(); 
});
```

The Error that I am getting is :

> An error occurred in ClientFunction code: ReferenceError: viewProgram
>   is not defined

Please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: Do you need the first () on viewProgram().click()? viewProgram isn't a function

Comment: Yes viewprogram returns mutiple elements and I have to click on first element. I tried with const clickViewProgram = ClientFunction(() => viewProgram.click()) as well but it is also not working and returns me the same error viewProgram is not defined

Answer (score 5):

Client functions cannot access variables defined in the outer scope in test code (refer to [Client functions limitations](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#limitations)), so you need to pass `viewProgram` selector as a [dependency](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#optionsdependencies):

```
const clickViewProgram = ClientFunction(() => viewProgram().click(), {
    dependencies: { viewProgram }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simple:

await t.click('tbody [viewBox]'); ?

Comment: I cannot use this, as this element is not visible. So, I think I have to use Client Function only

Comment: Could you please post an error you got if try this? As far as I know javascript see all items in html.
Also can you add how this button is hidden? Css or tags?

Comment: It throws error that : The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.

Comment: CSS for thsi element is``` <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="h-medium hover:text-brand w-medium"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path> <path d="M9 5v2h6.59L4 18.59 5.41 20 17 8.41V15h2V5z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>```